# Converting nested loop for faster computation of adjusted cosine similarity for sparse matrices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I have the following function for calculating adjusted cosine similarity. It takes in two numpy matrices. The mean centered ratings matrix is of size `22000 users x 503 items` and the similarity matrix is an empty matrix of size `22000 x 22000` since it is a user to user similarity. It takes hours to calculate similarity. How can I make it run faster?

```
def adjusted_cosine_similarity(ratings_centered_matrix, similarity_matrix): 
    for x in range(0, ratings_centered_matrix.shape[0]):  # get index of array
        for y in range(0, ratings_centered_matrix.shape[0]):
            s = np.sum(ratings_centered_matrix[x, :] * ratings_centered_matrix[y, :]
            si = np.sqrt(np.sum(ratings_centered_matrix[x, :] ** 2))
            sj = np.sqrt(np.sum(ratings_centered_matrix[y, :] ** 2))
            sim = s / (si * sj)
            similarity_matrix[x, y] = round(sim, 2)
            similarity_matrix[x, y] = sim
```

Comment: See if cdist helps - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

Comment: This method does not compute adjusted cosine similarity but just a simple cosine similarity. Also, I think it does not handle sparse matrices.

Comment: Lookup scikit learn pairwise calc methods.

Comment: Is the [tag:pandas] tag significant?  Sparsity in `pandas` is quite different from the `sparse` subpackage in `scipy`.  And what `sklearn` calls `sparse, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances.html